# Localhost- blank page while opening

Tags: c#, wcf, localhost

I was following MSDN [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms734712(v=VS.110).aspx) to create the WCF service, when I run it, it is correctly started, but when I follow localhost, the server is blank.

What can I do?

I am using Chrome, I've changed setting as it was suggested in many posts.

**ICalculator.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
   [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
       [OperationContract]
       double Add(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Substract(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
       [OperationContract]
       double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }  
}
```

**CalculatorService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{
    public class CalculatorService:ICalculator
    {
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Otrzymano: Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Wynik: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Substract(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 - n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Otrzymano: Substract({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Wynik: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Multiply(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 * n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Otrzymano: Multiply({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Wynik: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }

        public double Divide(double n1, double n2)
        {
            double result = n1 / n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Otrzymano: Divide({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            Console.WriteLine("Wynik: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Host:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using GettingStartedLib;

namespace GettingStartedHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Krok 1: utworzenie URI, które będzie służyło jako adres bazowy
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/");


            //Krok 2: utworzenie instancji obiektu ServiceHost (hosta serwera)
            ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), uri);


            try
            {
               //Krok 3: dodanie punktu końcowego serwera
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

                //Krok 4: umożliwienie wymiany metadanych
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;              
                selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                //Krok 5: uruchomienie hosta serwera
                selfHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Serwer jest gotowy!");
                Console.WriteLine("Naciśnij <ENTER>, by go zamknąć.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();

                //zamknięcie obiektu ServiceHost w celu zamknięcia serwera
                selfHost.Close();

            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wystąpił wyjątek: {0}",e.Message);
                selfHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config for library**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="GettingStartedLib.CalculatorService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.ICalculator">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**EDIT2:**

I followed @OmegaMan suggestion to test it with WCFTestClient. It gave me en error.

But when I tried the address: `http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/` (without CalculatorService even though it is said so in App.config) it works!

Why is that? It's weird.

**EDIT3:**
Ok, I've figured out that I need to add "/" in the *.config file in:

```
<add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService" />
```

so it goes like

```
<add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService/" />
```

**But can anybody tell me why my programming methods don't work? I mean if I change the address in *.config file (or leave it by default) it never works (the mentioned link- altough server starts properly)**

Answer (score 1):

Try changing localhost to the actual computer name or IP. I ran into a similar problem with my WCF service

Comment: u mean to change it while opening it with the Explorer? If yes, then well I did so and still the same (Internet Explorer throws http error 400)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about the service to suggest it will return a web page. It is a *service* web service which does operations.

Test it using the WCF Test Client found at `{Visual Studio Install Directory}\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe`. Once run select`Add Service` and in the dialog put in `http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService.svc`.

If it works with no error message it will show the interface definiton, such as mine below:

[image]

Then within the application you can test the different methods, such as `Add` in your case and then `Invoke` the operation.

Comment: It gave me en error, but can You read my 'Edit2'? Maybe You will know why is that happening? And WCFTestClient always gives me an error..